# Is there any way to print the Query result horizontally in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select * from TABLENAME WHERE "CLAUSE"
```

It will print the result in a single row.

```
Col 1    Col 2 ......  Col N                                                 
Val 1    Val 2 ......  Val N
```

I need

```
Col 1  Val 1            
Col 2  Val 2        
.       
.          
.        
Col N  Val N
```

Comment: And if you get 50 rows of data back, you'd display that as 51 columns? Or are you talking about dingle data row solutions?

Comment: Some GUI clients can do that for your.

Comment: "single", not "dingle". FFS

Answer (score 1):

A little time consuming to do on a regular basis, but:

```
select COL_NAME, COL_DATA
from  (SELECT * FROM table_name 
       WHERE clause)
  unpivot ( COL_NAME FOR COL_DATA IN ( COL1     as 'COL1'
                                      ,COL2     as 'COL2'
                                      ,COL3     as 'COL3'
                                      ,COL4     AS 'COL4') 
           )
```

Bear in mind that you also need to cast all of the values to the same data-type as Oracle won't mix datatypes in the same column, so if COL1-3 are number, but COL4 is varchar, then you would

```
select COL_NAME, COL_DATA
from  (SELECT * FROM table_name 
       WHERE clause)
  unpivot ( COL_NAME FOR COL_DATA IN ( TO_CHAR(COL1) as 'COL1'
                                      ,TO_CHAR(COL2) as 'COL2'
                                      ,TO_CHAR(COL3) as 'COL3'
                                      ,COL4          AS 'COL4') 
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'col 1', col1 from TABLENAME WHERE "CLAUSE"
UNION ALL
select 'col 2', col2 from TABLENAME WHERE "CLAUSE"
UNION ALL
...
select 'col n', coln from TABLENAME WHERE "CLAUSE"
order by 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help..  But it worked for same TYPE  of the column. For Eg. Select 'COL1', CIUDAD_ASEG_RECIBIDA(VARCHAR2) from SIM_X_AUTOS_CLTVAS_DET_RGO WHERE NUM_NEGOCIACION = 636
UNION
select 'COL1', DIRECCION_ASEG(VARCHAR2) from SIM_X_AUTOS_CLTVAS_DET_RGO WHERE NUM_NEGOCIACION = 636, if we use VARCHAR2 and Number, then it will raise error:**ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression**

Comment: You'd better convert the number (or any dates) to varchar2 in the query then ... you cannot have different data types in the sale column of the result set.

Comment: Also, you might want modify that to "WITH mydata as (SELECT * from tablename where clause) select 'col 1', col1 from mydata union ..." if it is a big table and if the where clause isn't well indexed to avoid multiple full table scans.